# How to get access token for Rumble API?

Tags: postman, rumble-api

I have a key and a secret.

According to https://dev.rumbletalk.com/rest/authentication

I can issue a request to get an access token:

https://api.rumbletalk.com/token

passing key and secret as parameters:

[image]

However, I am getting

```
{
"type": "Exception",
"status": false,
"message": "Missing credentials: key, secret"
}
```

**Any idea why?**

Rumble API key and secret have correct values from the collection variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL

```
POST https://api.rumbletalk.com/token
```

Using `raw` instead of `form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

In body,

```json
{
   "key":"your key",
   "secret":"your secret"
}
```

[image]

##### cURL call

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.rumbletalk.com/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
   "key":"your key",
   "secret":"your secret"
}'
```

##### cURL Result

[image]

##### `node.js` call

Save as `demo.js`

```js
const axios = require("axios");

const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(
            'https://api.rumbletalk.com/token',
            {
              'key': 'your key',
              'secret': 'your secret'
            },
            {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
};

getToken()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

##### `node.js` Result

[image]

Comment: As you seem to have a working request, it does indeed look like this should be application/JSON.  It looks like the content-type is missing from the curl command in the documentation example.  As usually -d means application/x-www.form-urlencoded.

Comment: curl \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -X POST \
 -d "{\"key\":\"<your key>\",\"secret\":\"<your secret>\"}" \
 "https://api.rumbletalk.com/token"

Comment: Added cURL and node.js call example too.