# Why am I getting 403 Forbidden response trying to upload a video using Rumble API?

Tags: postman, rumble-api

This is a follow up of this post:
[How to get access token for Rumble API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031116/how-to-get-access-token-for-rumble-api/78031487)

I was able to get an access token, but I still cannot upload a file using the API.

I am following this documentation:
https://www.rumbleplayer.com/developers/Rumble-Upload-API.html

So, I generated an access token and created a request, where I pass that access token along with all the required parameters (yes, I checked {{access_token}} has its value):

[image]

However, I am getting 403 Forbidden response.

Any idea why?

Comment: I try it but I got 403 error also I think paid plan only available this Image upload call.